# ads:loadAdOnCreate value controlled by bools.res/values/bools.xml

Tags: android, admob

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="enableAds">true</bool> <!-- true or false -->
</resources>
```

this is what res/values/bools.xml looks like.

then I'm doing

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admobPubId"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="@bool/enableAds"/>
```

but it won't work. any ideas why? it should work http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Bool

Comment: what's wrong with just saying `ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"` per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/banner_xml)?

Comment: i want it to be controlled by res/values/bools.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your **adview** in separate xml and **include** it wherever required.

**Ex:
adview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.ads.AdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    googleads:adSize="BANNER"
    googleads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
    googleads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

**other.xml**

```
<include layout="@layout/adview" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this is an issue with your code but think it's an issue with the AdMob SDK. I'm guessing they're just interpreting that as a `String` and converting it instead of taking it in as a `Boolean`.

Don't know if there's much you can do outside of declaring it in your `Strings.xml` instead.

Comment: I initially tried in strings.xml but I don't remember it working. I ended up giving up on xml and doing it via onCreate